# Stopping tethering through USB cable on Mac OS X and iPhone

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, bluetooth

I use iPhone tethering with Mac OS X, and it all works fine. I prefer to use it over bluetooth only. However, when I plug in the cable, it automatically tethers (which is annoying as when I plug it in I only want to charge or sync - for tethering I prefer it to be explicit).

I would rather not turn tethering on and off on the network setting on the phone as that gets annoying.

Is there anyway I can ensure tethering only happens via bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the network priorities of you network devices, so you computer will not use the iPhone, but that will not stop it from tethering. If you are using a 3G or 3GS, you could buy a USB-cable for the iPhone classic, which will charge, but not connect your iPhone.